# My pause statement is not working for pygame loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My collide_rect function is not working as I expect to be. The problem is when press the key 'r', it should be able to reset everything and continue the game. But when I actually press the key 'r', it does not change anything when I add in the pause statement. I want to have the game pause when two of the sprites I have(ball, obstacle) collide. After the user inputs the letter 'r', it should go back to running and reset position for both sprites. The error I am getting is when I press the key 'r', it does not change anything on the surface.

This is my while loop:

```
paused = False

def display_text(text):
    font = pygame.freetype.Font('helvetica.ttc', 32)
    text_attributed = font.render_to(gameDisplay, (300,300), text, black)


while not crashed:
    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    obstacle.change_x()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ball.jump_true()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                ball.jump_true()
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                paused = not paused



    if ball.collide == True:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        display_text('You Lost! type "R" to restart')
        paused = True


    if paused == True:
        ball.reset_position()
        obstacle.reset_position()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)

    else:
        ball.jump()
        ball.test_collision(obstacle)
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        ball.update()
        obstacle.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you need more code, just ask me for it and I will edit the code in. Please do not downvote unless you really think this is a bad question.

Comment: it will be interesting to see where you set `paused = True` and if this is before `paused = False`

Comment: Please also explain what happens exactly. "not working correctly" is too vague.

Comment: @mucio no, I have tried using find in IDLE but paused only showed up when I intiated paused as paused = False , when I checked for collision in my while loop where I set it to True, and in the if statements.

Comment: @Valentino thank you, I have edited the code

Comment: I think you need to add the relevant code to hope for a spot-on answer. The collision detection function, and the main loop where `paused` flag is originally switched.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overcomplicate things. You don't need multiple event loops. Use 1 main loop, 1 event loop and a state which indicates if the game is paused. e.g.:

```py
paused = False
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r

                # Toggle pause
                paused = not paused

    if paused:

        # "pause" mode
        # [...]

    else

        # "run" mode
        # [...]

    # update display etc.
    # [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it wasn't able to solve my problem.